# XCUItest. When you try to tap on the enter button on the system keyboard, the test breaks and the main.m file opens

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

I am writing **UI** tests for a ready-made ios application. I have a window in which you need to enter a valid link and tap on the Enter key to go to the next window. But the test stops after the command **app.keyboards.buttons ["continue"].tap()** and the main.m file opens which looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1i3W.jpg)

I am new to ui testing. Please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: I’m assuming this does not happen when you manually press that button? Does the debugDescription show the presence of a button “continue”? I wonder if behind the scenes it my be the “return” button still?

Comment: If you press the button manually, the same thing happens. The same thing happens when trying to call debugDescription. The transition to the next window should occur by pressing the "enter" key on the system keyboard. But neither "debugDescription" nor "po app" work, and we go to the main.m window.

Comment: Then I’d guess it’s not a problem with XCUITest and instead a problem with your app.